# Force to use window.location.href in vue-router hash mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using `vue-router 3.0.1`, and the mode is `hash`.

The current url is:

```
/#/?type=1
```

I tried to use `window.location.href` for the same path, but different query parameter like this.

```
window.location.href = '/#/?type=2';
```

But the url of the browser changes, but nothing else happens.

At the first place, I am trying this, because `router.push` didn't re-render the component.

The original `window.location.href` should give the different result, but `vue-router` looks like to override `window.location.href`.

How can I force to move to `/#/?type=2`, in this case?

Comment: Don't try to force anything. Better solution is to update the component. There are ways https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `window.location.href` to make it work. The problem here is that the component is reused when you only update the query parameter and the component will not automatically re-render. One way to solve this issue is to watch the $route in your component. Here's an code example. You also can find the jsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Fourzero/cbnom5sL/22/.

## Html

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- You can use router-link to trigger the url change or router.push in your code -- it doesn't matter. -->
  <router-link to="/?type=2">type 2</router-link>
  <router-link to="/?type=1">type 1</router-link>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
const Bar = { 
  template: '<div>Type {{type}}</div>',
  data () {
    return { 
      type: ''
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.type = this.$route.query.type;
  },

  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      // Update the data type when the route changes. 
      this.type = to.query.type;
    }
  } 
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes: [
    { path: '', component: Bar },

  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

For detailed explanation, you can refer the official doc https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html.

Comment: I said I am using hash mode, and I have to.

Comment: It doesn't matter. changing the mode to 'hash' will work as well. I've updated my code example to reflect that. If you have some vue router code running in local server, you can see the `/#/?type=1` or `/#/?type=2` in your url and the component gets updated if you click the type 1 or type2 link or trigger from router push.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you!